# How to mark a feature file with @manualTesting such that scenarios inside it are never run

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I have a case for a feature file where we have to test emails and we can't. So we decided to mark the whole feature file as `@manualTesting` so that people know that it has to be manually tested.

I know how to create an annotation to be executed before or after but is there a way that when we mark some feature file with `@manualTesting` it never gets executed.

**Note:-** I don't want to add any `@excluded` or `@disabled` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the "tags" attribute of the CucumberOptions annotation to exclude that tag from being executed:

```
@CucumberOptions(..., tags = {"not @manualTesting", ...},...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tags in cucumber options will be the best way to do it.

If u r using 2.x version of cucumber tags dependency in your project then

```
tags={ "not @manualtesting"}
```

And if you are using 1x version then use

```
tags={"~@manualtesting"}
```

This will skip all features or scenarios tagges with @manualtesting.